# Efficient way to remove list of struct every iterate

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, migradoc

So here's the scenarios :

1. I have a struct to be create while sql transaction is running

```cs
public struct things{
   public string somestring{get; set;}
   public int someNumber{get; set;}
}

public List<things> populateList{
List<things> target = new List<things>();

//Some sql query to add item into lists

return target;
}
```

2. In some scenarios, the struct itself may have some big chunks in memory(imagine like having a thousand of struct instances). And i have a instance of pdfsharp following :

```cs
public void doPrintDocument{
//Instance of pdfsharp
foreach(things item in populateList()){
//Iterate every item inside populateList
//Adding them into row

//Remove list item after adding into row?
}
```

3.The idea is : how I can remove a list after iterate in order to dynamically adjust the memory, so it won't overflow.

Comment: You don't appear to have actually made any attempt at removing anything.  Sadly, questions about optimisations are off-topic.  _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_ and  _[Is it okay to ask for code optimization help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-code-optimization-help)_ for more information.

Comment: The question isn't clear. The garbage collector already clears orphaned objects.. You won't have any issues unless you intentionally keep the list around. A list with a few thousands of items isn't that big either. Are you having a memory leak and suspect the list is at fault? What does your query and list building code look like?

Comment: @MickyD this isn't a question about optimization - it's hard to understand *what* the question is. If the list isn't stored anywhere, there's nothing to remove. If the OP is trying to add 100K items to the list one-by-one, there are dozens of duplicates that explain about buffers and the `capacity` parameter. It *should* be closed until the OP explains the issue

Comment: What does `populateList` and why does it use a list? If you use EF you could use `ToList()` to load all results in a list. A better idea though would be to just return an `IEnumerable<things>` so you *don't* have to create that list at all. Lists use buffers internally and reallocate them when they get full, so adding 1024 items will result in 10 reallocations. You can avoid this by passing a `capacity` parameter with the expected number of items. It doesn't have to be accurate.

Comment: `//Remove list item after adding into row?` Don't worry about it - let the GC do its job.

Comment: That's kinda a plausible explanations. Thanks and sorry of being off-topic. :)

Comment: populateList = null